# Why does ethernet and wifi show the same graph in task manager?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, ethernet, network-adapter, task-manager

In my work laptop, I am using VPN and when I open Task Manager in Windows, Ethernet and Wifi show the same graph. I am only connected to wifi and have no ethernet cable attached to it.
I was wondering why they show the same graph?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is only a guess because I have not used Windows in many years... But maybe you are confusing "ethernet"/"wifi" _adapter_ versus _network_? The logical network does not care if the connected adapter (interface/NIC) is wireless or wired. It just creates a network allowing devices to communicate, and may be reporting _network_ traffic with little regard to adapter type.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager shows configured adapters, even if not in use.

This is what happens.

There is not much about Why?  So perhaps that is a question for Microsoft.

Task Manager shows all network devices (I checked a couple of machines) so then it is an interaction of the VPN configuration with Task Manager, that is how the VPN interacts with the active network connection.

.

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: I meant I see the exact content of your wifi graph also in the ethernet graph which seems weird. I am assuming it might be a VPN configuration.

Comment: Your VPN is using your Wireless but VPN may think it is wired (configuration as you point out) so that may be the reason, That combined with TM showing all devices.

Comment: Task Manager shows all network devices (I check a couple of machines) so then it is an interaction of the VPN configuration with TM.